# Я хочу создать оповещение на каждый день... нашел вот это... но он не дает оповещение при выходе из программы полностью

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *componentsForReferenceDate = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth ) fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    [componentsForReferenceDate setDay:27];
    [componentsForReferenceDate setMonth:10];
    [componentsForReferenceDate setYear:2016];

    NSDate *referenceDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:componentsForReferenceDate];

    // set components for time 7:00 a.m.

    NSDateComponents *componentsForFireDate = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond ) fromDate: referenceDate];


    [componentsForFireDate setHour:10];
    [componentsForFireDate setMinute:0];
    [componentsForFireDate setSecond:0];



    NSDate *fireDateOfNotification = [calendar dateFromComponents:componentsForFireDate];

    // Create the notification

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    notification.fireDate = fireDateOfNotification;
    notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"БЛАГОСЛОВИТЕ ПРОРОКА (с.а.в)"];
    notification.alertAction = @"go back";
    notification.userInfo= @{@"information": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some information"]};
    notification.repeatInterval= NSCalendarUnitDay;
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];

}
```

Comment: И вообще будет ли оповещение каждый день... Или предложите что ни будь... СПАСИБО!

Comment: что такое выход из программы полностью?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko имеется в виду при закрытии программы из многозадачности

Comment: когда вы убиваете программу метод `applicationDidEnterBackground` не вызывается. таким образом ваш будильник не создается

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko есть вариант сделать так чтоб работал?... И еще если программа не убита этот код будет оповещать каждый день ?

Comment: запускайте будильник сразу как программа открылась. Или если вам надо сначала получить данные, когда пользователь хочет запускать, то сразу как получили данные так и запускайте. будильник будет работать не зависимо от того запущена ли программа

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko пользователь не будет ничего менять... Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: положить весь код в didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Да вы были правы. Теперь оповещение приходит и после закрытия программы.. Но есть еще одна проблема: оповещение приходит не только по заданному времени и не один раз. Оповещения приходят 5-6 раз и когда себе вздумается

Comment: когда запускаете приложение отменяйте все ранее установленные алерты, когда запускаете алерт выводите время в консоль и смотрите на какое время он поставился

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko я извиняюсь за свое неведжество ... как отменяют реннее установленные алерты?

Comment: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];`